# Is calling secured rest api from insecure browser safe?

Tags: javascript, security, https

The browser is on `http://example.com`(insecure) and I am making ajax request to `POST https://anotherserver.com/buy`. Is this safe?

I thought https will encrypt my data anyway, why does it matter that the browser that hosting the html page is not secure? Wont my javascript code securely talk to the endpoint??

Answer (score 1):

It is un secure. Since you are on http, your data is exposed to interference. BTW, it also violates same origin policy.